# VBA code during Workbook opening

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any method/practice where I can put my code during a Workbook opening (a sort of a constructor method)?

I need to do some stuff before the user is ready to see all sheets

Comment: You mean something like the `Workbook_Open()` event?

Comment: Yes, it is called the `Workbook.Open` event and is documented in the VBA documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know how to that during the opening but I know that there is a method which is `workbook_open`. And if you put `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` statement on top of your code, you get pretty much what you want.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Some codes here
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Msgbox "Welcome to ANALYSIS TABS"
End Sub
```

http://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/run-macro-automatically-opening-workbook/